# "There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'" error with custom model and list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this dropdownlist in a view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Sale.TypeTransaction", ViewBag.typetransaction as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

As you can see, the name of the dropdownlist is `Sale.TypeTransaction` because `Sale` it's a model inside a custom model:

```
public class OfficeSale
{
    public OfficeSale()
    {
        SaleProductRelations = new List<SaleProductRelation>();
        Sale = new Sale();
    }
    public Sale Sale { get; set; }
    public List<SaleProductRelation> SaleProductRelations { get; set; }
}
```

`Sale` has the property `TypeTransaction`, it is a `string`. In my controller I fill the selectlist as follows:

```
    public ActionResult NewSale()
    {
        var list = new List<SelectListItem>();
        list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Cash", Value = "Cash" });
        list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Credit", Value = "Credit" });
        list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Promotion", Value = "Promotion" });

        ViewBag.typetransaction = list;
        return View(new OfficeSale());
    }
```

I know if my viewbag has the same name of my property the dropdownlist is filled. But I cannot Write `ViewBag.sale.typetransaction`. Do you have any idea to solve this? Thanks in advance.

OK I tried the following as @StephenMuecke suggested and it worked:

```
    public ActionResult NewSale()
    {
        var list = new List<string>();
        list.Add("Cash");
        list.Add("Credit");
        list.Add("Promotion");

        ViewBag.typetransaction = new SelectList(list);
        return View(new OfficeSale());
    }

@Html.DropDownList("Sale.TypeTransaction", ViewBag.typetransaction as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: The thing that bothers me is that the second parameter the dropdownlist should be IEnumerable, but you explicitly cast it to a concrete object that I believe is not implementing IEnumerable. Why?

Comment: Well, It works on other "normal" dropdownlists, it is because I'm creating a custom list of options.

Comment: Which helper's constructor you are trying to call?

Comment: You should never name the `SelectList` the same as the model property your trying to bind to, so tying to name it `ViewBag.sale.typetransaction` is exactly the wrong thing to do. You need to show the exact details of the error message your getting, but the error is because `ViewBag.typetransaction` is `null`. It needs to be either `ViewBag.typetransaction as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, or if the error is occuring when you POST, its because you have not reassigned the value of `ViewBag.typetransaction`

Comment: I get this error when I enter to the page in the get. And the problem is the dropdownlist's name, if it was `TypeTransaction` it would work fine, but it would not bind the model in the controller.

Comment: @Franchesco, You get the error because your create `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` and then try and cast it to `SelectList` which cannot be done do its `null`! DO NOT try and name the `SelectList` the same as the model property.

Comment: Alternatively, if you want your view code to work, then in the controller it should be just `ViewBag.typetransaction = new SelectList(new List<string>() { "Cash", "Credit", "Promotion" });`

Comment: The constructor that I'm using is this `HtmlHelper.DropDownList(string name, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, object htmlAttributes)`. @StephenMuecke, yes it can be done, try it by yourself. Whatever I tried it with `IEnumerable` without the cast `as SelectList` and I got the same error. And I cannot name the selectlist as my property, because my property name's is `Sale.TypeTransaction`, it has a dot.

Comment: OMG. Read my last 2 comments. `SelectList` is `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` but `IEnumerable<SelectList>` IS NOT `SelectList` - your cant cast `Enumerable<SelectListItem>` to `SelectList`.

Comment: Yes StephenMuecke, I read it and I tried, but I got the same error, because the problem is the dropdownlist's name. A work around for me would be to put a Dropdownlist called TypeTransaction and bind it outside of the model in the controller, something like this `public ActionResult NewSale( OfficeSale model, string TypeTransaction)` and then to do this `model.Sale.TypeTransaction=TypeTransaction;`, but it is too ugly.

Comment: @Franchesco, It has nothing whatsoever to do with the the dropdownlist name. Edit you question to include the actual code your have now tried and I will fix it for you. And show the full error message!

Comment: @StephenMuecke - Maddening isn't it?  When people refuse to read what you are telling them, and double down on their problem...

Comment: @StephenMuecke hehe, sorry I tried again as I edited my question and it worked. You are right, But what if I want to add a `Text` and `Value`? Please answer not as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that in the controller your assign `ViewBag.typetransaction` to typeof `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` but then in the view you try and cast it to typeof `SelectList` which results in `ViewBag.typetransaction` being `null`.

`SelectList` is `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` (`SelectList` derives from `MultiSelectList` which derives from `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`) but `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` **is not** `SelectList`

There a 2 options to solve this. First, in the view, cast the `ViewBag` property to the correct type in the html helper

```
@Html.DropDownList("Sale.TypeTransaction", ViewBag.typetransaction as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

or alternatively, in the view, create a `SelectList`, for example

```
ViewBag.typetransaction = new SelectList(new List<string>() { "Cash", "Credit", "Promotion" });
```

Comment: It works as you said. But why if the name of my dropdownlist is `@Html.DropDownList("TypeTransaction", ViewBag.typetransaction as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })` and using `List<SelectListItem>` then it works but it only binds a property called `TypeTransaction` in a model?

Comment: Because your adding a property `typetransaction` to the `ViewDataDictionary` via the `ViewBag` property. The second parameter `ViewBag.typetransaction as SelectList` is `null`, but the fallback is that the helper then looks at the `ViewDataDictionary` to see if "TypeTransaction" is not `null` and is `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` which it is, so it works. This is one of the many reasons why you should **never** name the `SelectList` the same as the name of a property your trying to bind to (the most common convention is to append "List" - e.g. `ViewBag.typetransactionList = ..`

Comment: And please, **always** use the strongly typed helpers - `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Sale.TypeTransaction, ...)`

Answer (score 0):

`ViewBag.typetransaction as SelectList` this bothers me a lot.

As the `DropDownList` helper expects the second parameter to be an `IEnumerable` (I believe you are calling this constructor https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470380%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) you might need to cast to `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` instead.